# Git clone issue in MSYS2 shell

Tags: git, shell, msys

I am trying to clone a GitHub repository from within an MSYS 2 shell on Windows. I installed `git` using the following command:

```
pacman -S git
```

After installing, I tried the following command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google/breakpad.git /src/breakpad
Cloning into '/src/breakpad'...
error: remote-curl: usage: git remote-curl <remote> [<url>]
```

What does that error message mean, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Does removing `.git` from the end of the remote url change anything?

Comment: If you `cd /src ; git clone https://github.com/google/breakpad.git`, what happens?

Comment: The .git extension is required, check out https://github.com/google/breakpad : it's not a git repo, it's a web page

Comment: I tried both options, still the exact same error, even without `.git`.

Comment: Try using `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/google/breakpad.git` and see if you get more information about what the failure is.

Comment: Still the exact same error :/

Comment: You missed the point.  Show us the diagnostic messages coming from the command.  It was meant to help get more logging not to make the command succeed.  We need to debug what is happening, and the command will help do that.  Please update your answer with the results.

Comment: The "diagnostic message" was the same error output. GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 made no effect at all unfortunately :/

Comment: You should have seen more output as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/jszakmeister/f843e62d27f0d0f9f9b643c3c611d7f2).  You can try adding `GIT_TRACE=1` as well.  That example is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/jszakmeister/75f58ed05586a69a448dd53cf311711c).  The point is that you can get a little more information to help you debug the problem.

Comment: With both variables set, I got this output: https://pastebin.com/Heth3kyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the same command using the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), directly from a simple `CMD` or from an msys2-based shell (using bash, which is included in Git for Windows)

I just tested it:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git
> bash
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git$ git clone https://github.com/google/breakpad.git
Cloning into 'breakpad'...
remote: Counting objects: 17345, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 17345 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 17341
Receiving objects: 100% (17345/17345), 39.39 MiB | 1.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (13586/13586), done.
```

Then you can go back to your original msys2 shell.